# laravel 6 using `$controller->callAction` to send data to another controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have 2 controller and I send data to second controller using `callAction`. This is what I have in my first controller

```
$controller = App::make('\App\Http\Controllers\EmailController');
$email = $controller->callAction('sendEmail', array('firstitem'=>'qweqw','seconditem' =>'asd'));
```

with the above code im expecting to get an array in the second controller. In my second controller I have

```
public function sendEmail($request){

        return ($request);
}
```

to check if i will get an array, but im getting only: `qweqw` which only the first item of the array.

What is the correct way to send or receive an array in this scenario

Comment: try `app('\App\Http\Controllers\EmailController')->sendEmail($params)`

Comment: i will try it give me a minute

Comment: @IGP hi i was not able to get the link for the tutorial im following so I cant link it here but your code works for me . Can you provide it as answer and explain why it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line should work.

```php
app('\App\Http\Controller\EmailController')->sendEmail($params)
```

`app('...')` is an alias for `App::make('...')`. The issue with your code is the `callAction` method.

You're already getting an instance of the `App\Http\Controller\EmailController` when you use `app('...')`.

The controller is, above all, a **Class**, and as such, you can use any public method it has, such as `sendEmail` by calling it directly and passing parameters as needed. (`->sendEmail($params)`).